# macOS Catalina (MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)) restarting after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

Gist - Macbook Pro restarts after sleep

I have the following setup,

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
- External Monitor using a HDMI-USBC dongle

I usually keep the Macbook screen open and use two screens for work. However, after I lock the screen (using Shift+Command+Q) and then reopen after sometime, it restarts.

I expect that the Macbook reopen at the login screen instead of restarting.

Help appreciated.